# É possível utilizar os Async Generators com a sintaxe ES5?

Tags: javascript, promises, iterator, async-await

Por exemplo, o código abaixo que cria um *async generator*:

```
async function* iterate() {
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    yield 3;
    return null;
}
```

Poderia ser utilizado com a sintaxe `for await...of`:

```
for await (const iteration of iterate()) {
    console.log(iteration); // 1, 2, 3
}
```

O código que gera o iterador é de uma biblioteca que usa TypeScript, então pode ser facilmente transpilado para outras versões do EcmaScript. Porém quero utilizar esse código de terceiro sem precisar de um processo de transpilação, mantendo a compatibilidade com navegadores mais antigos, como usar esse código com a sintaxe do ES5?

Fiz um teste transpilando tanto essa função como o loop que a utiliza, porém é utilizado um código complexo com a ajuda de várias funções, tornando de dificíl entendimento e manutenção

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- É possível, de forma simples, através da recursão em vez de usar um loop. Criei a função `asyncForeach`, que recebe um iterador e uma função de callback que será executado ao termino de cada promessa, nesse ponto, basta chamar novamente a função caso aquele iterador não tenha terminado

```js
async function* iterate() {
    yield new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 1));
    yield new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 2));;
    yield new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 3));;
    return null;
}

function asyncForeach(iterator, callback) {
    iterator.next().then(function(cursor) {
        if (!cursor.done) {
            callback(cursor.value)

            asyncForeach(iterator, callback);
        }
    });
}

asyncForeach(iterate(), console.log);

console.log('finish');
```

Porém, seu funcionamneto é um pouco diferente da sintaxe `for await...of`:

```js
(async () => {
    async function* iterate() {
        yield new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 1));
        yield new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 2));
        yield new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 3));
        return null;
    }

    for await (const iteration of iterate())
        console.log(iteration);

    console.log('finish');
})();
```

- Também é possível criar algo semelhante usando a sintaxe ES6 e transpilar pra uma versão anterior usando qualquer playground online com TypeScript, Babel, Rollup ou similar, e copiar o resultado para dentro do seu código:

```
function asyncForeach(iterator, callback) {
    for await (const iteration of iterator)
        callback(iteration);
}
```

Assim não é necessário adicionar um processo de build, porém, para atualizar esse código, seria necessário um certo retrabalho ao arrumar as configurações, apesar de que esse pedaço código muito dificilmente precisará de manutenção, já que é algo bem simples que pode usar qualquer iterador

- Se viável e vantajoso, pode ser adicionado um processo de build apenas nesse pedaço de código, porém nem sempre é
- Outra opção é usar a sintaxe ES6 e transpilar apenas o código necessário em tempo de execução, porém isso não é recomendado, já que o mesmo processo será repetido várias vezes a cada reload da página desnecessariamente
- Por último, seria usar alguma biblioteca utilitária que tenha uma função como a acima e seja compatível com o ES5, mas não conheço nenhuma

Answer (score 0):

É possível? É. É viavel? Não. Basicamente, terás que criar *tu* uma função que seja o awaiter e uma outra que seja o generator e depois chamas uma dentro da outra com o callback final sendo o que queres fazer com que aconteça.

Não é *nada* simples. E não consigo perceber o que ganharias daí, quando simplesmente podes fazer o codigo em ES6 e dizer ao transpiler para te gerar a versão para o browser que nao aguenta essa versão de javascript

Outra em alternativa, usares polyfills para isso; tanto o [core-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) como o [async-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-polyfill) podem ajudar.

Comment: Poderia exemplificar? Dependendo do projeto, adicionar uma etapa de build não vale a pena, seria adicionar complexidade desnecessária. Pode ser também que o código aonde vai ser utilizado seja de um projeto legado que não tenha uma forma sequer possível de adicionar a transpilação

Comment: @Costamilam se adicionar um build step é uma complexidade desnecessária, então terás que pensar qual é o ganho que tens em _manter_ uma função que retorne generators e awaiters. 

Mas a pergunta real é: _porquê_ é que o que estás a fazer _não_ suporta esta versão do javascript? é que se for um browser, é um browser bem antigo. Se for nodejs -- porque é que simplesmente nao fazes o upgrade para uma versão que suporte es6 ?

qualquer solução será melhor que fazer os generators e awaiters à mão.

Comment: Você parte do princípio que outras soluções são simples, mas nem sempre são, mesmo em atualizar o Node, que é em um ambiente que teoricamente você tem controle, pode gerar muitos problemas. O ES6 não tem compatibilidade para o Opera mini e parcial para o IE (generators, por exemplo, não tem suporte) mesmo nas versões mais recentes, apesar de serem navegadores pouco usados, ainda assim são usados, e compatibilidade é importante

Comment: Eu nao estou a partir do principio que todas sao simples, eu simplesmente olho para o problema de um ponto de vista de _trabalho que me dá a mantê-lo no futuro_: Fazer um step de build é estupidamente facil quando comparado com fazer e manter generators e yields recorrendo a promessas à antiga -- é de loucos. é fazivel? claro! mas abomino os dias em que o tinha que fazer. No entanto, e eu esqueci-me disso, podes sempre recorrer a polyfills que _ja existem_ que normalmente uso quando esse raro problema aparece. Editei a resposta para reflectir isso.